# Interval is too slow

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

Interval isn't running once per millisecond. The final number only gets to 459 before stopping. Less if there is more than just a line on the interval. On here it doesn't even move through the first thousand. What I want is for it to run once per second to let me know how far an interval is done. So if `testNum` is at 30, then I know that it's 97% of the way done `(2970/3000)`.

```js
let testNum = 3000
let testInt = setInterval(() => {
    testNum--
}, 1)
let testTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
    clearInterval(testInt)
    console.log('Final Number: ' + testNum)
}, 3000)
```

Comment: Browsers generally have a minimum interval of around 15 milliseconds.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Parameters:

> `delay`
>
> The time, in milliseconds (thousandths of a second), the timer should delay in between executions of the specified function or code. **If this parameter is less than 10, a value of 10 is used.**

Have a look at [Reasons for delays longer than specified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified) as well.